# Why is this code freezing up my PC?

Tags: java, io, client-server, server-side

It's so bad I got to do a hard reboot (Holding down on the power button) and it doesn't even give me time to debug, so I'm basically screwed if I don't get a answer on here. I know it's server sided (As It happens when I don't run the client, but also happens if I do).

Here is the Server Code:

```
package cypri.games.cybatarserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class CybatarServer extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    String verNum = "0.0.0";
    JScrollPane jsp;
    JTextArea mainText;
    boolean stopServer = false;
    boolean waitForPlayers = true;
    Vector<Player> playersConnected;
    byte playerID = -1;

    public CybatarServer(){
        playersConnected = new Vector<Player>();

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 100);

        this.setTitle("Cybatar Server " + verNum);

        mainText = new JTextArea(50, 10);
        mainText.setText("Welcome to CybatarServer "+ verNum + "!\n");
        mainText.setEditable(false);

        jsp = new JScrollPane(mainText);
        this.add(jsp);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CybatarServer cyserv = new CybatarServer();
        cyserv.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try { 
            final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(44444);


            while(!stopServer){
                if(waitForPlayers){
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            Socket clientSocket = null;
                                try {
                                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                playerID++;
                                new PlayerThread(playerID, playersConnected, mainText, playerID, clientSocket).start();
                                mainText.append("Player " + playerID + " connected!");

                        }
                    }).start();
                }

                else{
                    for(int i = 0; i < playersConnected.size(); i++){
                        playersConnected.get(i).update();
                    }
                }

                Thread.yield();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Is there anything in here that could cause my PC to completely freeze up? And if so how do I fix it?

Comment: Comment out parts and see if you can get the problem to stop. The first step to debugging something without a debugger is to isolate the problem code and get it to be as small as possible.

Comment: Is it repeatable?  Does it freeze you up every time?

Comment: Wait, what?  `...Server extends JFrame`...?  I'd seriously consider rearranging that -- the server might *own* a JFrame, but it shouldn't *be* one...

Comment: @cHao `... implements Runnable` ;-)

Comment: @assylias: Even weirder, IMO.  :)  There's all kinds of threading and SRP issues waiting to rear their ugly heads.  The threading issues shouldn't really take down the whole machine (it *is* a VM, after all), but it'd be quite enough to mess up the process.

Comment: Note, that this `cyserv.run();` obviously does not start a new thread but only executes `run()` method. A common beginner's mistake when comes to java threading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect

```
while(!stopServer){
   if(waitForPlayers){
       new Thread(new Runnable() {
         ....
```

is generating and invoking a huge number of threads. That will hit your machine hard in terms of CPU (running those threads) and memory (each thread allocates its own stack space).

I suspect instead you want to accept on incoming connections and *only then* allocate/start a thread. Note that this still leaves you open to a DOS attack (imagine if an unlimited number of players join) but that may not be a practical issue for you.

Comment: Hah, yeah the logic seems a bit off, while the server is running, and we are waiting for players... create a ton of threads that run...

Comment: Alright, that was it. It's what I get for writing code at 2am haha, thank you very much. I'll accept once I can.

Comment: It's already starting a new thread for each client. I think the while(!stopServer) loop needs to be moved inside the server thread.

Answer (score 3):

Side note: [run UI stuff in the UI thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

This part:

```
while(!stopServer){
    if(waitForPlayers){
         new Thread(...).start();
     }
}
```

is going to create a huge number of threads unless the stopServer or waitForPlayers flags are changed pretty quickcly. No surprise it hangs...

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're never setting `waitForPlayers` to `false`. So, every time your `while(!stopServer)` loops, you spawn a new thread, hence freezing up your computer.

Comment: waitForPlayers should be a blocking method, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Have obviously not tried running it, but this construct strikes me as a potential fork bomb:

```
              new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            ...
                            new PlayerThread(playerID, playersConnected, mainText, playerID, clientSocket).start();
                            ...
              }
```